# The problem of not finding React static files in Python

Tags: python, reactjs, django

The back end of my project is **Python** and I have used **RteactJS** for the front end.
When using the `python manage.py runserver` command, the project runs successfully, but it does not find the static files.

setting:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/clientApp/build/static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "static"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

url :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: You can try changing the second argument from`index` to `views.index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you collect your statics files?
If not use this command:
`python manage.py collectstatic`
after that, you can use this command to run your server:
`python manage.py runserver`

**If it's not working again try to change your code with this:**

settings:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR / "clientApp/build/static"),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static-cdn', 'static-root')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

urls:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    # add root static files
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

for more information, you can read this document:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/